# MySQL statement not correct

Tags: mysql

```
select   substring(member.own,3,4),  count (*)
 from member, amphur 
Where amphur.AMPHUR_CODE  = substring(member.own,3,4)
group by substring(member.own,3,4)
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) from member, amphur Where amphur.AMPHUR_CODE = substring(member.own,3,4) g' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space between `COUNT` and `(*)`. MySQL doesn't recognize "count" as a function if there's a space.

Comment: @tee: You would be able to use a function followed by spaces before "(" only if you set sql_mode = ignore_space;

Comment: #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Comment: @tee that's a new issue, unrelated to the syntax. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Illegal+mix+of+collations+

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(m.own,3,4), 
         COUNT(* ) AS cnt 
    FROM MEMBER AS m, 
         amphur AS a 
   WHERE a.AMPHUR_CODE COLLATE utf8_general_ci = SUBSTRING(m.own,3,4) 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(m.own,3,4)
```